# ¿Cómo convierto un byte string "b'uno'" en string normal?

Tags: python, string

tengo una lista muy grande con strings que tienen bytes adentro `["b'uno'", "b'dos'"]` como puedo convertirlos en strings normales sin usar algo parecido a `milista[0][2:-1]` y que sea compatible con python 2 y 3??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval("b'uno'")
'uno'
```

Python 3

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval("b'uno'")
b'uno'
```

Aunque sea `eval`, es seguro y no permite nada excepto los constantes

```
>>> literal_eval("1+1")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ast.py", line 91, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ast.py", line 90, in _convert
    return _convert_signed_num(node)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ast.py", line 63, in _convert_signed_num
    return _convert_num(node)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ast.py", line 55, in _convert_num
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.BinOp object at 0x7f596085b1d0>
```